# same URL for wordpress and the proxy server

Tags: wordpress, apache, proxypass

I am having a WordPress site running behind an apache proxy server
so, WordPress site URL is http://www.wordpress.com
proxy URL is http://www.proxy.com
How can I retain the URL of the proxy server on the browser even after forwarding proxy to WordPress?

what changes are to be made where to make them

Comment: this issue is solved by changing the site URL and home URL in the wp-config.php